# Xperia Z network item stuck in Network Manager applet

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

In the Network Manager applet on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I have an extra item called 'Xperia Z Network' with the network name 'Xperia Z' and a greyed out status 'disconnected'. Unfortunately I can't take a screenshot of the applet (it closes if I press print screen). This item is between 'Ethernet Network' and 'Wifi Networks'.

If I click on 'edit connections' the item is not there and there is no network by the same name to remove.

I do own an Xperia Z, so it somehow made a connection with it once. But the menu item remains there even if the phone is powered off and ubuntu rebooted. Also the only connection I ever made with the phone is by setting up a tethered hotspot from my phone, with a different name.

So why is the item in my Network Manager and how do I get it to go away and not reappear.

Comment: If you click "Edit connections...", can you see the network there? Can you remove it?

Comment: That's a good point, I had already checked, but forgot to mention it, I have added the information to my question.

Comment: Can you find it in (and perhaps remove it from) `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`?

Comment: It's not there.

Comment: Strange. I setup a tethering network just for this purpose, and a new file shows up in system-connections, with the name I gave to the network connection. Just to be sure, can you do a `sudo grep -R Xperia /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, the file was there, I just missed it. I have now removed the file and the item is gone.Thanks, do you have any thoughts on why it was there and how I can prevent it from showing up again? As it's not the connection I'm actually using. Also if you create an answer I will accept yours.

Comment: As long as you don't connect with the phone, the connection will not show up. If you really want to be sure, you could periodically do something like `find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ -name Xperia* -delete` (have cron run it as root, or at startup). Thank you for accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try "Edit connections..." from the Network Manager applet. If the connection does not show up in the list, or cannot be removed from the list, find the corresponding file in `/etc/Network Manager/system-connections` and remove it.